# How can I find log files only within 2 minutes of current time from log folder

Tags: shell, ksh

I am beginner to shell
I Have one log Folder where logs are getting generated in format as:

```
ACS_1/ACS1_Events_OG_Multiple_20200126_014453.log
ACS_2/ACS1_Events_OG_Multiple_20200126_014300.log
ACS_3/ACS1_Events_OG_Multiple_20200126_020553.log
```

I want to find logs which are falling in between 2 minutes of time (014315 to 014515)

I tried to use

```
find . -name "ACS1_Events_OG_Multiple_20200126_01[4][3,5]*"
```

but I'm not getting exact result, I have to create automated logs between any given time range.

Comment: Hi and welcome, you just need between `(014315 to 014515)` or it's an example ?

Comment: `find * -regex "ACS1_Events_OG_Multiple_20200126_014[3-5].*"`. But obviously you need the time to depend on..... on what ? 

Comment: Hi @Freeman ,thanks for the response ,
actually "(014315 to 014515)" is just an example i need it from current time till 2 minutes from current time

Comment: You tagged `ksh`, so fund might not have the option `-mmin`. Do you have an `awk` that supports `awk -v startdate="2015-01-01" -v starttime="02:05" 'BEGIN {
         printf("%s %s\n", startdate, starttime);
      split(startdate,A,"[-]");
      split(starttime,B,"[:]");
      T1=mktime(A[1] " " A[2] " " A[3] " " B[1] " " B[2] " 0");
      while ( i++ < 3) {
         if (i>1) printf("-o ");
         printf("-name ACS_3/ACS1_Events_OG_Multiple_%s*.log ", strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M",T1));
         T1+=60;
      }
   }'  ` ?

Answer (score 0):

so you can use `cmin`, just specify whether you want the time to be smaller or greater or equal to the time you want, using, respectively:

```
#smaller - you have to use - before your time
find your-location -cmin -your-time
#greater - you have to use + before your time
find your-location -cmin +your-time
#equal
find your-location -cmin  your-time
```

for example we wanna check 2 minutes from current time

```
find . -iname "ACS1_Events_OG_Multiple_*.log" -cmin -2
```

or even better, for example as you wrote you have `ACS1` `ACS2` `ACS3` so better to use `?` instead of number, like this :

```
find . -iname "ACS?_Events_OG_Multiple_*.log" -cmin -2
```

good luck